# Not able to fetch the data from other database in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to get the data from another database in Drupal 7. But I am not able to get the data. Here is the code what I have tried.

1. I have added another database information in settings.php

   ```
   $databases['default']['default'] = array(
     'driver' => 'mysql',
     'database' => 'drupal_testing',
     'username' => 'root',
     'password' => '',
     'host' => 'localhost',
     'prefix' => '',
   );
   $databases['sakshi']['default'] = array(
     'driver' => 'mysql',
     'database' => 'test',
     'username' => 'root',
     'password' => '',
     'host' => 'localhost',
     'prefix' => '',
   );
   ```
2. And added the code in page.tpl.php for testing the connection.

   ```
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padtop30">
               <h4> DB Connection test </h4>
               <?php 
               try{
                   echo "inside try block";
                   db_set_active('sakshi');
                   $results = db_query("select name from test.user_names where phone = 432323");
                   $records = $results->fetchAll();
                   foreach ($records as $record) {
                     echo $record;
                   }
               }catch(\PDOException $ex){
                   echo "inside catch block";
                   echo $ex;
               }finally{
                   echo "finally block is executed";
                   db_set_active('default');
               }   
               ?>
           </div>
   ```

Now when i am loading the data (refreshing the page) i am getting the error like

```
    'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.semaphore' doesn't exist' in E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\database\database.inc:2227 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\database\database.inc(2227): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\database\database.inc(697): DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array) #2 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\database\database.inc(2406): DatabaseConnection->query('SELECT expire, ...', Array, Array) #3 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\lock.inc(167): db_query('SELECT expire, ...', Array) #4 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\lock.inc(146): lock_may_be_available('rules_get_cache...') #5 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\sites\all\modules\rules\rules.module(368): lock_acquire('rules_get_cache...', 60) #6 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\sites\all\modules\rules\rules.module(1026): rules_get_cache('event_watchdog') #7 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\sites\all\modules\rules\modules\events.inc(180): rules_invoke_event('watchdog', Array) #8 [internal function]: rules_watchdog(Array) #9 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\module.inc(926): call_user_func_array('rules_watchdog', Array) #10 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\bootstrap.inc(1997): module_invoke('rules', 'watchdog', Array) #11 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\errors.inc(210): watchdog('php', '%type: !message...', Array, 3) #12 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\errors.inc(75): _drupal_log_error(Array, true) #13 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\bootstrap.inc(2576): _drupal_error_handler_real(4096, 'Object of class...', 'E:\\xampp5.6.20\\...', 321, Array) #14 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\sites\all\themes\my_theme\page.tpl.php(321): _drupal_error_handler(4096, 'Object of class...', 'E:\\xampp5.6.20\\...', 321, Array) #15 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\theme.inc(1526): include('E:\\xampp5.6.20\\...') #16 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\theme.inc(1208): theme_render_template('sites/all/theme...', Array) #17 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\common.inc(6045): theme('page', Array) #18 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\common.inc(5907): drupal_render(Array) #19 E:\xampp5.6.20\htdocs\drupal\drupal-7.53\includes\common.inc(2748): drupal_render_page('
```

I am new to Drupal. Can any one help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While according to the documentation, there is nothing wrong with the way you have set up your second connection, I have never been able to get it to work like that. The only way I have had it working is with the below, although I would agree there doesn't seem to be anything fundamentally different:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
        array (
          'database' => 'drupal_db',
          'username' => 'root',
          'password' => 'password',
          'host' => 'localhost',
          'port' => '',
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'prefix' => '',
        ),
    ),

  'second_database' =>
    array (
      'default' =>
        array (
           'driver' => 'mysql',
           'database' => 'second_db',
           'username' => 'root',
           'password' => 'password',
           'host' => 'localhost',
           'port' => '',
           'prefix' => '',
        ),
   ),
);
```

Then you should be able to do db_set_active('second_database').

The "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.semaphore' doesn't exist'" message is usually when Drupal has tried to do something Drupally while still attached to your second database, so don't forget to do db_set_active() to return the connection back to the Drupal database. There is no need to add 'default' as default is the assumed default database.

You should do this directly after fetching the data you need. So in your example, it should come after `$records = $results->fetchAll();`

Or, if you only need this connection in one place/ infrequently, you could set it up on the fly. More info [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-connect-to-multiple-databases-within-drupal)

Hope this helps